# Raw RSA encryption (aka ECB/NoPadding) under .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa

I consider feasibility and performance under .NET (using C#) of the verification part of a standard RSA signature scheme that is not directly supported. Towards that goals, I need the raw RSA public-key encryption function *x → (x<sup>65537</sup>) mod N* (where *x* is a byte array as wide as the public modulus *N* is, like 256 bytes).

On other platforms, the standard technique is to implement that function using RSA encryption with no padding (Java's Cipher with "RSA/ECB/NoPadding"). But I can't find how to perform this under .NET. What are my options?

Comment: There is always the possibility of using the BigInteger class to implement textbook RSA yourself.

Comment: Have you looked into the Bouncy Castle providers for .NET? http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/ or https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET doesn't provide this functionality inbox.  If you're just doing public key operations then you can use the `BigInteger` class without having security liabilities. (Don't use it for private key operations, because a) it'll have your private key fairly obviously in memory and b) it doesn't have a Montgomery Ladder based ModPow, so it would leak the Hamming Weight of your private key)

```
RSA existingKey = HoweverYouWereGettingAKey();
RSAParameters rsaParams = existingKey.ExportParameters(false);

BigInteger n = PrepareBigInteger(rsaParams.Modulus);
BigInteger e = PrepareBigInteger(rsaParams.Exponent);
BigInteger sig = PrepareBigInteger(signature);
BigInteger paddedMsgVal = BigInteger.ModPow(sig, e, n);

byte[] paddedMsg = paddedMsgVal.ToArray();

if (paddedMsg[paddedMsg.Length - 1] == 0)
{
    Array.Resize(ref paddedMsg, paddedMsg.Length - 1);
}

Array.Reverse(paddedMsg);
// paddedMsg is now ready.

private static BigInteger PrepareBigInteger(byte[] unsignedBigEndian)
{
    // Leave an extra 0x00 byte so that the sign bit is clear
    byte[] tmp = new byte[unsignedBigEndian.Length + 1];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(unsignedBigEndian, 0, tmp, 1, unsignedBigInteger.Length);
    Array.Reverse(tmp);
    return new BigInteger(tmp);
}
```